# How to do "massive" Job Scheduling (Quartz?)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have a general question related to the quartz scheduling framework:

I need to perform a task after a fixed amount of time after a user registration. For the sake of simplicity let's say exactly 1 hour after registration of a user in my system. The job MUST be done, even if the system is restarting during this one hour the task must be remembered and it MUST be performed later if my system is down at the usual time.

Is this something where I can or where I would use Quartz? I looked at persistent jobs which looks quite promising but I am not sure if this will still work out for 1000 jobs a day. Furthermore, I am not sure about the performance implications. Maybe someone can help me with information here.

If Quartz is not the right choice, which other ways/frameworks do you see for this issue? My application is a Java 6/Spring 3 based Web-App.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1000 jobs per day is not "massive", it's not even "a lot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using quartz persisted job store successfully in our production environment for a SaaS platform application where 100s of jobs are running.